# How to INSERT list mariadb where multiple values are excpected only list given

Tags: python, mariadb, bulkinsert

I want to insert a list (bulk insert) into mariadb using python. However the insert has 5 arguments and I only want to give the list as an argument. It will make sense if you read the code.
If I try to insert only the event_list with the first block of code I get the following error:

```
mariadb.ProgrammingError: statement (5) doesn't match the number of data elements (23305).
```

The below code is the code I want (But it doesn't work)

```
@classmethod
def insert_data(cls, event_list):
    """Adds events to the database

    Args:
        events ([string]): Name of events
        :param event_list: list of events
    """

    try:
        DB.create(
            f"INSERT INTO Events(road_name, avg_speed, flow_count, ts_event, uuid)  VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
            event_list)
    except Error:
        return Error
```

The event_list contains all the events

An example of the values in event_list:

> ('A2', '84', '13', '2022-12-06T10:34:12.867Z', 'e9af9383-2d7f-4963-88c9-38aa1d9c33cc')

There can also be a None type in an event (I don't think that matters at all with this issue)

> ('A9', None, None, '2022-12-06T10:34:14.436Z', '49c10cd1-3029-4367-a557-010d5eb1334a')

with the current insert statement it inserts every row one by one which takes a long time(therefore the bulk insert idea).
The below code is my code now, where for every row it makes an insert instead of inserting all of the rows at one go.

```
@classmethod
def insert_data(cls, road_name, avg_speed, flow_count, ts_event, uuid):
    """Adds events to the database

    Args:
        events ([string]): Name of events
        :param road_name:
        :param avg_speed:
        :param flow_count:
        :param ts_event:
        :param uuid:
    """
    db_values = (road_name, avg_speed, flow_count, ts_event, uuid)
    try:
        DB.create(
            'INSERT INTO Events(road_name, avg_speed, flow_count, ts_event, uuid)  VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)',
            db_values)
    except Error:
        print(Error)
```

This is the function to add all the events in the db:

```
@classmethod
def add_all_events(cls):
    # combined_events = DataEndpointFetcher.combine_matching_events()
    with open('../refactored_ndw_data.json') as json_file:
        combined_events = json.load(json_file)
    event_list = list()
    for event in tqdm(combined_events['events']):
        try:
            road_name = event['lanelocation']['road']

            avg_speed = event["avgspeed"].get("kmph")

            flow_count = event["flow"].get("count")

            ts_event = event['ts_event']

            uuid = event['measuring_point_id'].get("uuid")
        except:
            continue

        event_list.append((road_name, avg_speed, flow_count, ts_event, uuid))
    EventModel.insert_data(event_list)
```

So my question: How do I INSERT with only the list given as an argument for VALUES.

Comment: @snakecharmerb The exception says `mariadb.ProgrammingError` so it's the mariadb module, which supports qmark, pyformat and format paramstyle.

Answer (score 1):

You can use {} paramstyle of Python as:

```
DB.create(
  'INSERT INTO EVENTS(road_name, avg_speed, flow_count, ts_event, uuid) VALUES{}'.format(db_values)
)
```

`db_values` as you created is a tuple which can be indexed, and 5 ?'s requires 5 variables to be passed.

```
DB.create(
  'INSERT INTO Events(road_name, avg_speed, flow_count, ts_event, uuid) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', db_values[0], db_values[1], db_values[2], db_values[3], db_values[4]
)
```

Comment: I meant to say instead of the 5 values I give: VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', db_values[0], db_values[1], db_values[2], db_values[3], db_values[4], I only want to give te list containing all of the events as a value so that the insert statement is only called ones and not O(n)

Comment: Yes, you wanted to use a single variable `db_values` for all the input values. See the updated answer with {} paramstyle.

Comment: When I use the .format I get the following error: 'mariadb.ProgrammingError: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '[('A2', '84', '13', '2022-12-06T10:34:12.867Z', 'e9af9383-2d7f-4963-88c9-38aa...' at line 1